# Updating the Product changes previous product price (eg. 99,000 to 99) Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento2.3.0, product-prices

I am facing a strange issue in Magento 2.3.0 admin whenever I try to update the product, the price change automatically (eg. ₦ 99,000 to ₦ 99) I guess there is something wrong while saving the value if I update the price removing the comma everything works great.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's a default behavior.** Use **99,000.00** instead.

**If you use comma(,) only** then that will be considered as decimal point and your price will be saved accordingly.

```
Ex : 
99,000 will be saved as 99.00
99,009 will be saved as 99.01 (rounding applied)
```

**If you use both comma(,) and period(.)** then period(.) will be considered as decimal point and comma(,) will be ignored.

```
Ex : 
99,000.00 will be saved as 99,000.00
99,00.9 will be saved as 9,900.90
```

Comment: ThanQ so much I was really confused because of this.