# Problem with changing price in admin

Tags: magento2, save, product-prices

As described in this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305010/updating-the-product-changes-previous-product-price-eg-99-000-to-99-magento-2)
in Magento 2 if I insert a new product or update an existing one using only comma in price
it uses it as a decimal separator.

Example: if I set the price to 10,000 it gets saved as 10.0000.

I tried with a before plugin on Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save that takes out the commas in price from request but it still behaves like stated above.

How can I change this programatically? Is there a class I can use a plugin in or a preference perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to add a comma, So that you can display it on the storefront ( frontend ) see that field is a float set in the database ok, No code helps you as you know it gets used by multiple functions it will also not be a get choice

Instead, use some function manipulation for frontend

[image]

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Best practice, Don't use comma while entering the product prices.

You can check on the **price.js** which render the product price for every products in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install currency formatter extension and try.This Currency Formatter Extension can be used with multiple stores.

**https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-currency-formatter/**

And Get more information read mageplaza documentation

**https://docs.mageplaza.com/currency-formatter/**

**`THANKS.`**